# How to pass objects from templates to views in django?

Tags: django, templates, object, view

This must have been asked before but I can't find one.

I have retrieved my_object = get_object_or_404(MyObject, id=obj_id) in my view.
I pass it to a template.
Now I want to pass the same my_object to another view when user clicks a link.

```
<a href="/another_page/my_object.id">here</a>
```

But then I'll have to retrieve my_object by it's id again in the second view.
Can I send the entire my_object somehow?

I've seen examples where url_pattern has \d+ or \w+ to receive integer or string variable but how to pass objects?.

Comment: @agf that looks like a fine answer

Comment: @agf: can you make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, I'll move it. I just normally don't like to post really short answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You must retrieve object again in detail view. Write get_absolute_url for model and call it in templates.