# Django : How to pass objects from template to views?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343938/how-to-pass-objects-from-templates-to-views-in-django)  is similar to my question but the answer didn't work for me.
I create the object 'mark' and use it to instantiate a form as follows:

```
mark = marklist.objects.filter(subject=facultyuser.sub)[0]
form = MarklistForm(instance=mark)
```

I then pass it to my template . Now from the template how can I pass the 'mark' object to another view as an argument ? 
I need to use it as an instance in the other view like this -

```
form = MarklistForm(data=request.POST, instance=mark)
```

Help will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: using: `request.session['mark] = mark` and get from another view `request.session.get('mark', None)`

Comment: I did try that but I was get the error : object of type 'marklist' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Error here? `request.session['mark] = mark`

Comment: yes...I was getting the error on using that session and I couldnt find a relation between that and JSON so I dropped that approach

Comment: You can change the value of SESSION_SERIALIZER in your settings.py to get back the behaviour from Django before version 1.6.

`SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'`

Answer (score 0):

send the object using html forms

```
<form action="your/view/url" method="post">
    {{form.as_table}}
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>    
</form>
```

and in your view use

```
form = MarklistForm(data=request.POST, instance=mark)
```

Comment: Well, I need the <td></td> tags in my html since I am using data-tables...and I did try form.as_table but it just displayed a blank page...no grid was displayed :(

Comment: what your {{form}} in template is showing? if it's blank then check your view. Maybe you are not sending the form in context.